# Uploading a file to java

Tags: java, html, servlets, jetty

I have been working on this for 2 days and am finally giving up and asking here. I want to be able to upload a (text) file to a PC. This project that I am working further on uses jetty to serve the pages. Here is the code from my end so far:

HTML part:

```
    <form action="upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="file" />
            <input type="submit" />
    </form>
```

Java part1:

```
    ContextHandler uploadContext = new ContextHandler();
    uploadContext.setContextPath("/upload");
    uploadContext.setBaseResource(getBaseResource());
    uploadContext.setClassLoader(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
    uploadContext.setHandler(new UploadHandler());

    HandlerList handlers = new HandlerList();
    handlers.setHandlers(new Handler[] {uploadContext, configContext, sendGcodeContext, adjustManualLocationContext, getSystemStateContext, resourceHandler, new DefaultHandler()});
```

Java part 2:

```
public class UploadHandler extends AbstractHandler{
    @Override
    public void handle(String target,Request baseRequest,HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {

                   Part filePart = request.getPart("file"); // Retrieves <input type="file" name="file">
                   String filename = getFilename(filePart);
                   System.out.println(filename);
                   baseRequest.setHandled(true);
    }
}

private static String getFilename(Part part) {
    for (String cd : part.getHeader("content-disposition").split(";")) {
        if (cd.trim().startsWith("filename")) {
            String filename = cd.substring(cd.indexOf('=') + 1).trim().replace("\"", "");
            return filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf('/') + 1).substring(filename.lastIndexOf('\\') + 1); // MSIE fix.
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

As you can see, the file handling itself isn't present yet; only the file name so far since this already doesn't work.

The following message will be presented:

> HTTP 500 error with error:Content-Type != multipart/form-data

Could anybody please help? I am getting really frustrated that it still doesn't work.

Kind regards,
Daniël

Comment: Are you really submitting with the form you posted, or did you start using some ajax you didn't post? I've seen a few questions like that recently. Just because you made the form 'multipart/form-data' doesn't mean a loosely related Ajax post will be too.

Comment: The HTML code above is literately the code that i am using to test it. Other handlers are using gets which are done with ajax, but since i am using files i have to use post. so to your question, no i am not using ajax for this test